# Примеры микросервисов

Tags: микросервисы

Ищу тут потихоньку новую работу, чтобы получить новые знания, и столкнулся с таким вопросом, на который хз как ответить, тк с микросервисами не работал. Вопрос такой: Какие микросервисы вы знаете?

Но разве микросервис это не просто подход, при котором мы делим одну сущность на множество мелких независимых?

Comment: Может имеются в виду какие-то фреймворки для создания микросервисов?

Comment: @CrazyElf вполне может быть, но вопрос был буквально такой